# Check if Firebase sign in is successful React.js

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have an app with dynamic rendering. After a user signs in I want to load content. When they pressed the sign in button in my Welcome component my signUpPressed function executes:

```
signUpPressed = () => {
    console.log("signUpPressed called")
    let email = this.state.email
    let password = this.state.password
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code
      var errorMessage = error.message
      console.log(errorCode)
      console.log(errorMessage)
    })
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
      console.log("user is" + user)
      this.props.handler(true)
    }
  }
```

However, I have to press it twice before the handler I pass to this Welcome component from the App component calls. I tried doing a .then or a .finally but couldn't figure it out. My App.js code looks like this:

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    loggedIn: false
  }

  handler = (val) => {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: val
    })
  }
```

What should I do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the user, using the method  `onAuthStateChanged` as in the following sample from the official documentation:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

The listener itself is for detecting changes; you define the logged in/logged out behavior from within, according to the user object.

When there is no user, user will be null, so your signed-out case will happen;

when there is a user, the object will be truthy, triggering the signed in case, with a lot of properties on it, like user.email etc -- see the docs for more.

You can check directly within the handler, or you use the handler to flag something outside of itself, and check that.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user0

Comment: A good idea would be to wrap this in an `AuthContext`, that way he could consume it anywhere in his app.

Comment: I tried using that code too, the issue is that if I call `this.props.handler(true)` where `//User is signed in` I get an issue with the keyword `this`. The way I have it now, when the user clicks sign in, they are signed in, however the handler doesn't call because it's asyncronous

Comment: You check directly within the handler, or you use the handler to flag something outside of itself, and check that.

Comment: @jackantico No problem. Since you're a new contributor, gentle reminder to click the ✓ check mark and the up-arrow at the left of my answer to indicate to other users that this solved your problem, so they know when searching.

Comment: Okay so I tried that and it doesn't work... basically, I want to know if there is a way to run some code after the sign in or the sign up were successful. Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured it out (posting in case anyone else gets stuck here). In the end, this code worked for me, it let me change the state of my parent component only when I knew for sure the sign in was successful.

```
signInPressed = () => {
    console.log("signInPressed called")
    let email = this.state.email
    let password = this.state.password
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((user) => {
        if (user != null) {
          console.log("user is signed in")
          this.props.handler(true)
        } else {
          console.log("user isn't signed in")
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code
        var errorMessage = error.message
        console.log(errorCode)
        console.log(errorMessage)
    })
  }
```